# Can't get a JSON without "" symbols to parse in swift (watch kit)

Tags: json, swift

I am making a watch kit / Apple Watch app that needs to take in a JSON response the problem is 'normal' JSONs look like that:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

while the JSON I am trying to use looks like that:

```
{
    flag: false,
    abuses: null,
    recoubs_by_users_channels: [ ],
    favourite: true,
    recoub: false,
    like: false,
    dislike: false,
    in_my_best2015: false,
    id: 72838304,
    type: "Coub::Simple",
    permalink: "16xwc3",
    ...
```

I tested the func I wrote below and it worked 100% on the top JSON but not on the bottom one! (I suspect that the lack of `""` symbols may cause this problem)

JSON Struct:

```
struct Test: Decodable {
    let flag: Bool
    let favourite: Bool
    let title: String
}
```

JSON fetching func:

```
func fetchJSON() {

    let jsonUrlString = "https://coub.com/api/v2/coubs/16xwc3"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let err = err {
                print("Failed to get data from URL:", err)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()



                // decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase



                let course = try decoder.decode(Test.self, from: data)


                self.label1.setText("Flag: \(course.flag)")
                self.label2.setText("Favourite: \(course.favourite)")
                self.label2.setText("Title: \(course.title)")
            } catch let jsonErr {

                print("")
                print("")
                print("")
                    print("Failed to decode JSON:", jsonErr)
                print("")
                print("")
                print("")

            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I would like to get this func to work (read the values) with that "weird" looking JSON!

Comment: The JSON at the link is valid and your code works if you declare `flag` as optional: `let flag: Bool?`

Comment: Wow xd that's an oopsie on my side! Thank you very much! You helped me out a lot! :)